# I need you can not access file to extension

Tags: .htaccess

my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request sent by the browser includes index.php...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
# forbid access (403)
RewriteRule ^. - [F]

# Then you just need a generic rule to rewrite /mysite into index.php
RewriteRule ^mysite index.php [L]
```

I need you can not access: www.mysite.com/mysite.php, I can only access it: www.mysite.com/mysite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you only need to add a `$` behind `mysite`. You already block access to index.php, but your second rule matched `mysite`, as well as any other url that started with `mysite`, including `mysite.php` and `mysite/is/awesome.gif`.

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request sent by the browser includes index.php...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
# forbid access (403)
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# Then you just need a generic rule to rewrite /mysite into index.php
RewriteRule ^mysite$ index.php [L]
```

Please note that you can use `RewriteRule ^ -` instead of `RewriteRule ^. -`. The latter one requires that there is at least 1 character while the first one matches everything, which is not a problem in this case, but might bite you later when you try to write something that is match-all.